# How to remove english alphabets from list in python

Tags: python, non-english

I have a list with some English text while other in [Hindi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi). I want to remove all elements from list written in English. How to achieve that?

**Example**: How to remove `hello` from list `L` below?

```
L = ['मैसेज','खेलना','दारा','hello','मुद्रण']  

for i in range(len(L)):    
    print L[i]
```

Expected Output:

```
मैसेज    
खेलना    
दारा    
मुद्रण
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `isalpha()` function

```
l = ['मैसेज', 'खेलना', 'दारा', 'hello', 'मुद्रण']
for word in l:
    if not word.isalpha():
        print word
```

will give you the result:

```
मैसेज
खेलना
दारा
मुद्रण
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> import re
>>> i = ['मैसेज','खेलना','दारा','hello','मुद्रण']
>>> [w for w in i if not re.match(r'[A-Z]+', w, re.I)]
['मैसेज', 'खेलना', 'दारा', 'मुद्रण']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` with regex `match`:

```
import re
list(filter(lambda w: not re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]+', w), ['मैसेज','खेलना','दारा','hello','मुद्रण']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's regular expression module.

```
import re
l=['मैसेज','खेलना','दारा','hello','मुद्रण']
for string in l:
    if not re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]', string):
        print(string)
```